# Reading HTTP file attachment as string

Tags: c#, webclient, mime

I am using a `WebRequest` to make a `GET` and the response includes an attachment.

The attachment is a html file that I want to strip the content out between the  tags. I have managed to get the call working with the following code:

```
string URI = "http://www.sample.com/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fReports&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=MHTML&OrganisationID=" + organisationID;

CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
cc.Add(new Uri(URI), "NTLM", new NetworkCredential(userName, userPassword, userDomain));

WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(URI);
req.Credentials = cc;
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
string response = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
```

The response, when i look in Fiddler is :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: multipart/related
Expires: Wed, 02 Apr 2014 14:35:15 GMT
Set-Cookie:  RSExecutionSession%3a%2fPuborts%2fSecreal%2fClub+Meip+Ret=0yu4f1455xnmznu55; path=/
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
FileExtension: mhtml
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Blah Report.mhtml"
Date: Wed, 02 Apr 2014 14:36:15 GMT
Content-Length: 84215

MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related;
boundary="----=_NextPart_01C35DB7.4B204430"
X-MSSQLRS-ProducerVersion: V10.50.4000.0

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

------=_NextPart_01C35DB7.4B204430
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="Blah Membership Report"
Content-Type: text/html;
name="Club Membership Report";
charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

PCFET0NUWVBFIEhUTUwgUFVCTElDICItLy9XM0MvL0RURCBIVE1MIDQuMDEgVHJhbnNpdGlvbmFs
------=_NextPart_01C35DB7.4B204430--
```

How can I get hold of just the attachment and read the contents into a string please?

Answer (score 0):

The "attachment" part is just to enforce a save as screen in the browser.

You can use a normal WebClient

```
        var client = new WebClient();
         using (client)
               {
                 client.Credentials = blablabla
                 var result = client.DownloadString("http://blablabla.com");
                }
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I have just tried your example and I get the same results :(